# Avoid using linearlayout for autospacing

Tags: android, android-layout, lint

Currently I am using empty `LinearLayout`s for autospacing items inside other `LinearLayouts`s.

```
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:orientation="horizontal"
>
    <ImageView/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView/>
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView/>
</LinearLayout>
```

However, it produces Lint warning: `"Useless leaf layout: This LinearLayout view is useless (no children, no background, no id, no style)".`
It there other method for autospacing, to avoid such a warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a [`Space`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html) View.

As the documentation says,

> Space is a lightweight View subclass that may be used to create gaps between components in general purpose layouts.

Alternatively, it looks like you are just using these Views to center the `ImageView`.
If this is the case, you could use [`android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_gravity) on your `ImageView` to center it horizontally within the parent `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use - 
1. Space View 
2. you can also provide padding or margin.